# Google chart doesn't show correct behavior in php

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

So I have database where that gets random values at random times. example:

2019-02-22 12:05, 500
2019-02-22 12:15, 2
2019-02-22 12:19, 90

So I want to show it in a line chart. this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"><script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
 </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisTickColors);

function drawAxisTickColors() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Price');
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');

  var dateArr2 = (<?php echo json_encode($dateArr); ?>);

  var number = (<?php echo json_encode($number); ?>);

  var length = Math.min(dateArr2.length, number.length);
  var rows = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
       rows.push([number[i], new Date(dateArr2[i]) ]);
  }

  data.addRows(rows);

  var options = {
  // backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4',
  curveType: 'function',
  chartArea: {
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%"
},
hAxis: {
  textPosition: 'none',
  baselineColor: 'none',
  gridlines: {
    color: 'none'
  },
},
vAxis: {
  textPosition: 'none',
  baselineColor: 'none',
  gridlines: {
    color: 'none'
  }
},
colors: ['#2098d4', '#ffffff'],
legend: 'none'
};

var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
chart.draw(data, options);
}
 </script>
```

and this is how my database looks like this:

[image]

But my chart looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong, please help.

EDIT

tried this:

```
number = number.map(Number);
```

after

```
var number = (<?php echo json_encode($number); ?>);
```

this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you use `data.addColumn('number', 'Price')` i.e. number instead of string?

Comment: @SalmanA no, because I get the error: value 10 is not a number.

Comment: Of course it does. You also need to convert `"500"` to 500 e.g. `var number = <?php ... ?>; number = number.map(Number)`. The chart should work after it I guess.

Comment: @SalmanA well it did somethig I will edit my post to show you what it did

Comment: Dates need to be along the x-axis, right (I think you're adding them on y).

Comment: @SalmanA so how do I add the date to the x-as, I am very new to this, so please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each chart has a specific [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format),
for `LineChart`, the first column is used as the x-axis,
each additional column appears on the y-axis.

in this case, to have the date on the x-axis,
just swap the order of the columns...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Price');
```

and...

```
rows.push([new Date(dateArr2[i]), number[i]]);
```

---

ALSO, you're using an old version of google charts.
`jsapi` should no longer be used, see [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code),
this will only change the `load` statement.

from...

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisTickColors);
```

to...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisTickColors);
```

note: the `line` package is not needed, it is for *material* charts...

```
google.charts.Line
```

you're using a *classic* chart...

```
google.visualization.LineChart
```